# how to make responsive gallery

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: This is first image when width is max]

Hey programmers..
I am in trouble.I want to make the gallery using html, css ,bootstrap. (I know js and also I am still learning).

I want to make it complete responsive but its not working as when I decrease the width the image that I store in div goes down. 
I make the image responsive and div also responsive.
I know div is block element so it goes down.I also use span also but its also not working .You can see in pic that I have uploaded.

This contain multiple image in the  row.
Things that i want , when i decrease the width of browser(medium device like laptop ~~1200px) to sm( ~~992px) the image size should drecease and after that the image shift to new line .and same for all view
this all thing apply  for laptop user  as the browser size decease  the image hide.

**the image  also  shift down when width decease i don't want it, it so awakward  **

Comment: can you make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar  can u explain it more, i will see it on net

Comment: try to replicate the issue on jsfiddle.net so that we can solve your problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap then copy paste this code:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><!--you can add more section like this-->
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

This will work definitely for you.

Comment: i want many thing from this gallery , when i shrink the width the image should shrink (responsive) but  after the limit reached the the image shieft to new line

Comment: the thing u suggest me, i aplied it also  image not shrink and  the requried width of image is  on obtained

Comment: Put img-responsive class like this : <img class="img-responsive">

Comment: this is working more better for one image , i have multiple image of width 242px for desktop  version 5 image in row. the things is that the image goes down as shown in  pic that i uploaded

Comment: @subham kapoor you can do it by extending bootstrap library like following link.
you have to add those code : https://blog.polarbits.co/2014/02/16/quick-tips-5-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap/

Comment: okky i will do, i not get time , i will do it today